# How to read post curl request in android and read response

Tags: android, curl

I am implementing a rest API and now I have to execute following request and then read the response from server. Can anybody guide me or provide me a piece of code to implement it in Android

```
$ curl `http://xyz.com:84545/api/locks/` 
 -X POST \
 -H "Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2012 01:23:45 GMT" 
 -H "Authorization: SABH ZW1haWxAaG9zdC5jb20Mohoehglsdofsdofjsdfjsdfjsdj DUzMjNhOTg=" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"i":0,"u":1,"h":1,"m":"2312312312","n":"Lock"}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html). Code snippet can be found [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient).

Comment: I can put 'Date', 'Authorization' and 'Content-Type' to BasicNameValuePair but how to put last json data into HttpPost or how can I send this data to server?

Comment: Date, Authorization etc are header parameters, so you should be using `addHeader` method of the `HttpPost` object. The JSON data is the payload and should go in the `setEntity` as a [`StringEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html)